# Win 7 OEM - replaced Mobo, won't boot

Tags: windows-7

Power surge took out video cards and motherboard. I purchased a replacement of the same motherboard (MSI ga-z97x gaming 3). Before replacement I was able to boot the computer without the video cards in, just using onboard video. Replaced board and Windows fails, reboots at black screen loading drivers. It used to stop at the AVG drivers, so I removed those manually. Still same now.

There are some unique things here, but I don't think they matter.

originally this was set to RAID 0 through the BIOS. It has two SSDs for the boot drive in that RAID. HOWEVER, I've gone around that. Before swapping the board I cloned the boot drive(s) to a single HDD I had on hand and verified Windows would boot from it. It booted find after telling it to start normally. I realize the RAID won't work on the new board in all likelihood, so I won't mess with that; I'll just work to get this clone going, then clone back to the SSDs, this time in RAID 1 (no need for striping, but since  have the drive, might as well mirror).

So, I assume it won't boot due to HAL, but since it's the same board (even the same Rev), I thought it should. Is there some manual way for me to get this going? Also, it's an OEM Windows 7 Home Prem. license. Every Win 7 disc I've used to attempt a repair says it's the wrong version. Key on side of machine doesn't say if it's x86 or x64. Do I need an OEM ISO/disc? If so, where can I get that?

Sadly, can't go to Win 10 with this one.

Comment: You don't indicate what version of Windows 7 you had (Home Basic, Professional, Home Premium, ect) the language pack and any regional editions they were all unique.  So you have to determine which edition of Windows 7 you were/are using.  [How you convert that ISO to an OEM is easy though.](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062)

Comment: Home Premium 64-bit. Good news, I have the disc. I'll work on running the repair and see what happens.